# Conditional commands in discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I want a user to be able to find out about something by, for example, saying something like !ask [___]. I would have a certain list of things that it could ask. Specifically, what notes are in a certain musical scale. So they would ask !scale Cmajor and get a response of "the notes in C major are C,D,E,F,G,A,B." I'm an absolute beginner and have no idea how to do this. I've made one bot before, but that's all my python experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can view how to do such a task from the discord.py [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

Specifically something like this could work, assuming you're using the latest version of discord.py, and following the appropriate setup:

```
# This is assuming your prefix is already defined, and you have a general bot setup
@bot.command()
async def scale(ctx, arg): # assuming the prefix is !, the command will be !scale argument
    if arg.lower() == "cmajor":
        await ctx.send("The notes in C major are C,D,E,F,G,A,B.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Invalid scale.") # add more scales as needed
```